# In Python, how can you split a dataset of strings containing name and address into separate columns.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large dataset with names and addresses in single strings (in other words, in a single cell in Excel):

- John Smith 2 Summer Street
- Adam Jones 37 Winter Street
- Daniel Owens 192 Autumn Street

The big picture is that I want to separate the name and address into separate columns in Excel. I figured that Python might be useful here. My beginner approach has been to try and create code to "locate" the first number in each string and insert a semi-colon before it. I've found a way only to do it to one address at a time, but I want to do it across the whole dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.DataFrame(["John Smith 2 Summer Street", " Adam Jones 37 Winter Street", "Daniel Owens 192 Autumn Street"])
s[0] = s[0].str.split()
s.iloc[0,0].insert(3,';')
s.iloc[0,0] = ' '.join(s.iloc[0,0])
```

If someone can help with my current method, or has a much easier method to suggest to split the columns, then that would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat self-explanatory ("\d" is a digit, "\D" is not a digit").

```
s[0].str.extract("(\D+)(\d+\D+)")
#               0                  1
#0    John Smith     2 Summer Street
#1    Adam Jones    37 Winter Street
#2  Daniel Owens   192 Autumn Street
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Another question though - how would I go about separating this: "John Smith Flat 4b 2 Summer Street", into this: "John Smith Flat" "4b 2 Summer Street" (I do want to keep the Flat part in the name, unless there is an easy way to include it in the second column.) At the moment it ends up with something like: "John Smith Flat" "1" and removes the rest of the address. So how would I go about keeping **everything** after the first number in the second column?

Comment: here's what seems to do the trick: s[0].str.extract("(\D+)(\d+.*)")